# Passing multi array in Objective C to a function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass a multi array (for example 3x3) to be printed in a matrice type form using Objective C. 
I'm fairly new to the language and am stuck. I can pass a single array, however with multi arrays I get the error Array type has incomplete element type.

```
void printMat(float value[][], int rows, int col)
{
    int j, k;
    float printpt;

    //Handles coloum printing
    for (k=0; k<col; k++)
    {
        NSLog(@"/n");
    //Handles row printing
    for (j=0; j<rows; j++)
    {
        printpt = value[j][k];
        NSLog(@"%f ", printpt);
    }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the function with

```
printMat(A, n, n)
```

Where A is the float A[30][30] and n=30.
What the best way to achieve this or to pass multi dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass it as `float *value`, then calculate the offset into the array appropriately. `value[j*cols+k]`.

Note: [data is held in the following order](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node10.html#SECTION001050000000000000000) - first row (all), second row (all) etc)).

`value[]` is not incomplete because it behaves as `value*`.

However, `value[][]` is incomplete, because it has no way to understand the first `[]` array subscript without knowing the dimension of the second.  For the same reason the statement `value[j][k]` makes no sense - without knowing the rowsize, how can you address the columns?

`float value[][30]` works fine, but won't help you because you want to supply a variable size.

Comment: 'float value **' or 'float **value'?

Answer (score 1):

well for one thing this is not objective-C (with the exception of the NSLog statements) .... in objective-c you would simply create the arrays like so:

```
NSArray *row1 = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3,nil];
NSArray *row2 = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:obj3,obj4,obj5,nil];

NSArray *matrix  = [NSArray arrayWithPjects:row1,row2,nil];
```

and then you function prototype would simply be:

```
-(void) printMat:(NSArray *)matrix;
```

Comment: arrayWithPjects? I guess thats a typo.

Comment: The main reason I avoided NSArray was due to being application requiring up to 40x40 matrices (signal processing).